# UIPopoverController disappear when the orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

How to make a change in orientation UIPopoverController did not disappear?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's not clear what your goal is. Thank you.

Comment: What's the meaning of the "make a change"??

Comment: plzz make the question more clear?

Comment: I think it's "How to make a change in orientation, keep UIPopoverController did not disappear?" :) although long time ago.